# Magento 2 : How Edit Product Detail Page Layout - Luma Theme as Parent

Tags: product, magento-2.1, layout, theme, layout-update

I have created theme by using **Luma** as parent theme.

I have updated header and footer area by customising `default.xml` in `app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/`. It works without any issue. Also I have updated home page layout by updateing `cms_index_index.xml` in  `/app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mytheme/Magento_Cms/layout/`. It is also working & I can update layout.

But to edit single product page layout, I have created `cata‌​log_product_view.xml` in `/app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/`. But that layout can't update single product view page.

Here is the Magento dev doc link.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

I have added below code in `cata‌​log_product_view.xml` file & there is no effect.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs`i:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
  <css src="css/zoo.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.price" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Why this layout is not working for single product page?

Comment: Please check for extension. Any custom or third party extension override that view xml file ?

Comment: It is a default Magento 2 installation and there is no any 3rd party / custom plugin. I just created new theme by considering `luma` as parent.

Comment: Now it is working. I don't know the reason.

I just copied `catalog_category_view.xml` from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/` & edited the file. It is working now.